# Nginx store HTML form data to .csv silently failing

Tags: php, html, csv, nginx

I have a website, hosted on a server running Nginx. I have a form on a page, contact.php, and I want to add the entered data to a new line on a .csv file.

Currently, the issue is that the CSV is not edited or created, if the file doesn't exist.

I have tried looking in the server logs, and there isnt anything particularly helpful.  The server logs show a code 200 for the file contact.php that the form is on.

I have tried seeting the file perms to 777 temporarily - doesn't change anything.

Here is a minimal version of my code:

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];


if(!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone)){

$cvsData = $name . "," . $email . "," . $phone ;

$fp = fopen("data.csv","a"); 
echo "123";  //this line is reached
    if($fp)
    {
        echo "456"; //this line is not reached
        fwrite($fp,$cvsData."\n"); 
        fclose($fp); 
    } 
}
?>
```

Is there anything in particular that I should be looking for here? Is using method="post" in the form submission correct? Is there some way to verify that the file is being opened correctly in the php script? I'm quite new to php.

Comment: You aren't closing the file, is the first thing I see.

Comment: And what do you think you're accomplishing here? `$no_rows = ($no_rows -1) + 1;`

Comment: @miken32 That was just some serial number code which I actually don't need. Removed that and added an fclose.

Comment: You also haven't said what your problem is.

Comment: @miken32 sorry, the issue is that the .csv file doesnt get edited

Comment: Delete the CSV file and try running your code. Does a new CSV file get created? If not, probably it's a permissions problem. Also, ditching the `$_POST` stuff and putting the values into your question would make it easier to reproduce. See [mcve].

Comment: @miken32 the CSV file does not get created. I tried changing the permissions of the folder, and the permissions of an existing CSV file, but no possible permission setting changed anything. I've changed the code to a minimal version that still has the same issue as well

Comment: I imagine a minimal version would be `var_dump(file_put_contents("data.csv", "test"));` and see if it's true or false (it's going to be false.) Have you tried specifying a full path to the file? Or putting it in a different directory? There's nothing wrong with your code, it's a permissions problem.

Comment: @miken32 putting the csv and php files in another directory worked. thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Glad I could help!